# Rails on Nginx + Phusion Passenger: "It looks like Bundler could not find a gem. Maybe you didn't install all the gems that this application needs."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have a Rails app running using Nginx and Phusion Passenger. Everything worked fine for many months, but after the last deploy, I got an error "We're sorry, but something went wrong.".

The Nginx log tells this:

```
[ 2016-05-11 13:28:26.5617 17187/7ff504072700 App/Implementation.cpp:303 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/a4aa2/rails/current: An error occured while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: 4153f320
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-VPT6E4.html
  Message from application: <p>It looks like Bundler could not find a gem. Maybe you didn't install all the gems that this application needs. To install your gems, please run:</p>

  <pre class="commands">bundle install</pre>

<p>If that didn't work, then the problem is probably caused by your application being run under a different environment than it's supposed to. Please check the following:</p>

<ol>
  <li>Is this app supposed to be run as the <code>a4aa2</code> user?</li>
  <li>Is this app being run on the correct Ruby interpreter? Below you will
      see which Ruby interpreter Phusion Passenger attempted to use.</li>
</ol>

<p>-------- The exception is as follows: -------</p>
Could not find mime-types-2.99.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
...etc...
```

My gems seem to be all available:

```
[a4aa2@bellatrix ~]$ cd rails/current/
[a4aa2@bellatrix current]$ bundle
Using rake 10.5.0
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
...etc...
Bundle complete! 91 Gemfile dependencies, 113 gems now installed.
Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
```

I have no idea how to debug this. The only thing I can think of is re-installing phusion passenger and try again.

I'm on a hosted service. Is it possible that there's another Nginx process/installation running that didn't run before, and now things are messed up between those two?

Comment: It seems the version of your ruby is changed..try switching the ruby version

Comment: `$ ruby -v` gives me `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]`. I have a `.ruby-version` file where I can switch ruby, but to which should I switch? Which one does passenger run on? And how could this change?

Answer (score -4):

try bundle update:

```
bundle update
```

Comment: Please don't. This is bad advice. You never want to run `bundle update` without specific arguments. So `bundle update <problematic_gem_name>` maybe, but even then I don't think that's the solution to the problem at hand.